# calculating number of months and generate tickets on each month

Tags: php

I am trying to generate support request automatically on the basis of user entered start date and end date.

1st I will calculate the number of months between 2 date, then I will raise support request on every month till it reaches end date.

I am trying like this

```
if($frequency=='Monthly') {

 $ts1 = strtotime($sdate);
 $ts2 = strtotime($edate);
 $year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
 $year2 = date('Y', $ts2);
 $month1 = date('m', $ts1);
 $month2 = date('m', $ts2);

 $diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);

 for($i=1; $i<=$diff; $i++)
 {


    $time = strtotime($sdate);
    $final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SUPPORT REQUEST QUERY");
 }
}
```

for ex: start date is 2017-06-19, and end date is 2017-08-21, then the support request should be generated 3 times, on 2017-06-19, 2017-07-19 and 2017-08-19

plz suggest how to go ahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no need to calculate number of months, unless you want to store it in database or use it somewhere.

You can just take start date and end date from users and raise tickets on the frequency you want by following this code.

```
$startdate = "2017-06-19";//here is start date
$enddate = "2017-08-21";//end date
$tempdate = $startdate;//temporary storing start date
//comparing tempdate is not greater than end date
while(strtotime($tempdate)<=strtotime($enddate))
{
    //this is my sample code. You can replace with yours.
    echo "Raised ticket on ".$tempdate."<br/>";
    $tempdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($tempdate)));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Raised ticket on 2017-06-19
Raised ticket on 2017-07-19
Raised ticket on 2017-08-19
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sdate = "2017-06-19";
$edate = "2017-08-18";

$d1 = new DateTime($sdate);
$d2 = new DateTime($edate);
$diff = $d1->diff($d2)->m;

$Tickets = array($sdate);
$time = strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($sdate));

for($i=1; $i<=$diff; $i++)
{
    $Tickets[] = date("Y-m-d", $time);
    $time = strtotime("+1 month", $time);
    //$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SUPPORT REQUEST QUERY");
}

var_dump($Tickets);
```

Now you have the tickets in the array $Tickets

EDIT; Noticed the diff calculation used in question does not work if the end day is lower than start day. Changed to DateTime.
Demo: https://3v4l.org/8UVRM